# Getting the 'base' url Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, url

I'm not sure if I have used the right terminology here but Is there a way I can get the base URL of my app?

My problem Is I have a login service that has a hardcoded redirectUrl now when I'm in development, I'm obviously using `http://localhost:4200` but when I've published I'm using my website name `https://mywebsite.com` now Is there a way I can grab that and not anything after so like If I go to `https://mywebsite.com/thisadad` I only get back `https://mywebsite.com`?

Now I know I could have a function on the ngOnit of my app.component where I grab the URL on first load pass it to a service and then use it throughout the app but that wont work If I say enter the page at `https://mywebsite.com/newpage` is there a better way to do this??

The reason I'm using a hardcoded redirect is because I'm using auth0 as my authetication

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hard-coding URL in app is nasty. Try something from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922466/redirect-user-with-router-depending-on-logged-in-status

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the situation currently, 
In your case you should use a global variable named
'environment'.
Which you configure during build ( ng build ) 
More on this in this article:
https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be